# Updating WDDM 1.0 to WDDM 1.1

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I tried to install Windows emulator in my Windows 7 System. I note that I need to update my Graphics card config, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

I have DirectX 11 with  WDDM 1.0.

I wish to update my Graphics card drives. I wish to update from WDDM 1.0 to WDDM 1.1.

Are there any ways to do in Windows 7 32-bit system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a WDDM 1.1 driver from you graphics adapter manufacturer.  If they don't offer one, you're probably out of luck and need a new(er) graphics adapter that has WDDM 1.1 drivers available.

Comment: How can I find which graphics card manufacturer I have in my PC?

Comment: Really?  Ok, try Windows' Device Manager, or run something like [CPU-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), or maybe look at your original invoice from when you bought the system, or maybe even open the system and look at it. :)